# Creating a back button to use in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, colors

So I'm currently working on a little project website, which basically has changes the background color when pressing a button. But I am also trying to implement a "back" button to go backwards in the color array which I created and in which all color codes that are being generated will be saved. But as you may see when testing the project the back button doesn't quite work and I get that thats due to the "i" variable not being saved when calling the "prevColor" function´.

```
function prevColor() {
  (i == randomColors.length ? bodyStyle.backgroundColor = randomColors[i-2] : bodyStyle.backgroundColor = randomColors[i-1])
};
```

This is the part that doesnt work out for me, but feel free to check the whole code on jsfiddle.net through the link provided below, or through the snippet (click to Open).

https://jsfiddle.net/jamal000/kobmajyx/

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#change");
var buttonStyle = button.style;
var bodyStyle = document.querySelector("body").style;
var p = document.querySelector("p");
var i = 0;
var randomColors = [];
var hue;
var HSLcolor;
var back = document.querySelector("#back");


button.addEventListener("click", randomHSL);
back.addEventListener("click", prevColor);

function randomHSL(){
  hue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 360) + 1);
  HSLcolor = `HSL(${hue}, 80%, 70%)`;

  bodyStyle.backgroundColor = HSLcolor;
  randomColors.push(`${HSLcolor}`);

  p.textContent = "Color: " + randomColors[i];
  i++;

  p.style.color, buttonStyle.borderColor = `HSL(${hue + 180}, 80%, 70%)`;
  p.style.color = buttonStyle.borderColor;
};

function prevColor(){
  (i == randomColors.length ? bodyStyle.backgroundColor = randomColors[i-2] :    bodyStyle.backgroundColor = randomColors[i-1])
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#change {
  height: 40.6px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 5px 7px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#change:hover {
  color: #666666;
  box-shadow: 7px 10px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

:active {
  border-color: #666666;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

p {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#back {
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: 2px solid #2f2f2f;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#back:hover {
  border-color: #aaa;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;

}

#back:active {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  color: #aaa;
  background-color: inherit;
}

div {
  margin-right: 38.172px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Color Toggle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Color: White</p>

  <div>
    <button id="back"> &#9668; </button>
    <button id="change">Click for a surprise!!!</button>
  </div>

  <script src="toggle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: well since you're back by one, you need to update i when you click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the `i` value in the `prevColor()` method. Try this:

```
function prevColor() {
  if (randomColors.length > 0 && i > 0) {
    i--;
    bodyStyle.backgroundColor = randomColors[i]
    console.log(randomColors, i)
  }
};
```

Comment: I see how this solves one issue, I had the same idea, but my issue here is, when the prevColor function runs and I continue using the newColor function that the array canges; as in first its [random color 1, random color 2, random color 3(current)] (go back from random color 3 to RC 2) [random color 1, random color 2(current)] and now if i continue generating colors RC 3 wont be the same because a new one is generated. Its not a big deal but I'm just interested in how to fix it :)
Thank you very much anyways

Comment: @jamal000 You can use 2 different indices - `i` for adding colors (do only i++) and the other index `j` to keep track of the current color (you can do j-- for back and j++ for forward)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I want to clarify the UI

```
<p id="color"></p>
<p id="current"></p>
<button id="back"> &#9664; </button>
<button id="new">Click for a surprise!!!</button>
<button id="next"> &#9654; </button>
```

If we want to go back and forward, let's have separate buttons. And one more button for the surprise that will push new color to the array and set the index to that new color.

Then I would extract all DOM manipulations into a single method, let's call it `applyColor`. Also, I would have a default color value as the first item of the `colors` array. And `index` set to 0 appropriately. So the script should can push new color to the `colors` array, shift color `index` and update the UI by the `applyColor()` calls.

```
const colors = ['white'];
let index = 0;

function applyColor() {
  const color = colors[index];
  bodyStyle.backgroundColor = color;
  colorElement.textContent = "Color: " + color;
  currentElement.textContent = (index + 1) + " / " + colors.length;
}

function generateColor() { // bound with click on "new" button
  const hue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 360) + 1);
  const HSLcolor = `HSL(${hue}, 80%, 70%)`;
  colors.push(HSLcolor);
  index = colors.length - 1;
  applyColor();
}

function prevColor(){ // bound with click on "back" button
  index -= index > 0 ? 1 : 0;
  applyColor();
}

function nextColor(){ // bound with click on "next" button
  index += index < colors.length - 1 ? 1: 0;
  applyColor();
}

applyColor();
```

Here's the updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dhilt/fz2dktxu/36/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but again same as with @SatyaSampathirao, the next color will again be randomly generated and not the one which had been before the prevColor function ran :/

Comment: @jamal000 I updated the answer. Maybe the result is a bit excessive, but I hope I was able to pass on some useful ideas.

Answer (score 0):

PLease check the link. I have updated your code by declaring the variables.

```
var HSLcolor;
var back = document.querySelector("#back");

> var randomColors = [];var i =0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kobmajyx/6/

Comment: this doesn't fix the issue? how does it help

Comment: thanks for the contribution, but i don't see how this fixes my issue

Comment: Jamal, What I figured from your question is that back button was not working. If that's correct then please chk the link that I have added.

Comment: Well it does kind of fix my issue, but your update can only go back by one color and if you go back and then press the "new color button" an new color is generated and not the one that was there before going back is used.
thank you anyways, I found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to start separating your presentation function from event handling, processing.

Your code should be something like https://jsfiddle.net/ryx2gn01/19/

- you have 2 actions : prevColor and newColor both change the state of the aplication and trigger a change on presentation:
- one internal processing function that would be the generation of your color (randomHSL)
- one presentation function that sets the values where you want them (setColor)

Now you have an array of hues (`randomColors`), and when you press "Suprise me" it should add a new hue value to the array and set the current index (variavel `i`) to the last color (because you want to show the color you just pushed into the array), so `i = randomColors.length - 1`

Upon pressing "Previous Color" you have 2 cases, your index is already in the beginning of the list (`i <= 0`) or is not the first (`i > 0`). In the first case you don't want to change your index, but on the second case you want to decrease by one, there fore the if...then...else you see on the function `prevColor`. Finally after change the state you call the function responsible for displaying the results `setColor(i)` passing the current index.

Hope you enjoy my solution, its not perfect but hope it helps you